# jQuery function calling twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jquery code, and once I call it the first part of the function initiates, but then right after that the second part initiates; it's like the if statement isn't working. Have i got any problems with my code?

```
$(".pinPane").click(function() 
{
    if ($('.pinPane').hasClass('open')) 
    {
        var htable = $('#content-panel-content').height();
        var wtable = $('#content-panel-content').width();
        var panew = wtable - 2;
        var paneh = htable * 0.7;
        var tableh = htable * 0.3;
        $('.pane')
            .height(paneh)
            .width(panew)
            .addClass('panepinned')
            .removeClass('shadow');
        $('#content-panel-content').height(tableh);
        $('.pinPane').addClass('cls').removeClass('open');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#content-panel-content').css('height', '100%');
        $('.pane').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=200px');
        $('.pane').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=40px');
    };
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any obvious errors. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah - it will no longer go into the `if` statement after the first click because the element no longer has the class `open`

Comment: I guess its because the last line inside `if` `$('.pinPane').addClass('cls').removeClass('open');`. It removes he class, so moving to else

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ : OP stated that his both if and else block are executing

Comment: @Arun `and once I call it the first part of the function initiates, but then right after that the second part initiates; it's like the if statement isn't working`

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the class pinPane? If so, your code is not written correctly. Are you binding `$(".pinPane").click(function()` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
 $('.pinPane').addClass('cls').removeClass('open');
```

use:

```
 $(this).addClass('cls').removeClass('open');
```

as in first case it will remove class from all elements with class `pinpane`. once u removed class then else code will be executed as now its not contain the open class.

if its calling twice then it can be case of event propagation. You can stop it by:

```
$(".pinPane").click(function(event) 
{
   event.stopPropagation();
   //rest of your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's like the if statement isn't working

Depending on your needs the following line of code inside your `click` handler may give unexpected result:

```
if ($('.pinPane').hasClass('open'))
```

Basically you check if any `.pinPane` has a class `open`; don't you want to only check the `.pinPane` that raised the `click` event? If so change it to:

```
$(".pinPane").click(function() 
{
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) { //note this here
    } else {
    };
});
```